# ValueError: item is not in list

Tags: python

I am making this simple code:

```
MyList=[]
valueA=1
valueB=2
valueC=3
MyList.append (valueA)
MyList.append (valueB)
MyList.append (valueC)
print (MyList)
print ([MyList].index(valueB))
```

I created it to try the [a].index(b) statement. As far as I know, and as far as I could find on the internet, this code should be fine.

I thought it would give the output: 0, because the index from valueB should be 0 (correct me if I'm wrong). Instead it gave the output:

```
    print ([MyList].index(valueB))
ValueError: 2 is not in list
```

I dont think there are any problems with the difference between integer, string and float.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[MyList]` is a list consisting of a single item, which is `MyList`.

I don't know why you have wrapped `MyList` in another list. You need to call `index` on `MyList` itself:

```
print(MyList.index(valueB))
```

And the result will be 1, not 0, because `valueB` is the second item in `MyList`.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, i am just starting with python, so a little bit of help can be usefull sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was that you put my_list into another anonymous list at the last line.It should be like this:

```
MyList=[]
valueA=1
valueB=2
valueC=3
MyList.append (valueA)
MyList.append (valueB)
MyList.append (valueC)
print (MyList)
print (MyList.index(valueB))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!If this helped you then let the community know by giving a vote up! :-)